# Программа для подсчета количества строк в файле *.txt - Java

Tags: java

Привет, собственно написал код программы, выполняющей следующее - пользователь пишет путь *.txt файлу, программа высчитывает сколько в документе строк, выводит количество строк на экран + создает файл *.txt в котором так же записывает количество строк. Вот код, пользуйтесь:

```
public class GetStrings {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Введите абсолютный путь к файлу: ");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String inputValue = scanner.next();
        String n = inputValue;

        try {

            File myFile = new File(n);
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(myFile);
            LineNumberReader lineNumberReader = new LineNumberReader(fileReader);

            int lineNumber = 0;

            while (lineNumberReader.readLine() != null) {
                lineNumber++;
            }

            System.out.println(lineNumber);

            lineNumberReader.close();

            String lineNumber1 = String.valueOf(lineNumber);
            File newFile = new File("d:\\myFile.txt");
            FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(newFile);
            fileWriter.write(lineNumber1 + " Строк в файле: " + n);
            fileWriter.close();


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

А теперь надумал сделать так, чтобы пользователь писал директорию, программа просматривала директорию на наличие файлов расширения *.txt и считала строки в каждом из документов, выводило все значения на экран и так же записывало их в новый файл *.txt. Написал код на считывания файлов в директории но не могу из вытащить каждую переменную файла в директории, что-бы посчитать количество строк. Вот наработка, но как её соединить, помогите)) :

```
public class Blabla {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Введите абсолютный путь: ");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String inputValue = scanner.next();
        String n = inputValue;

        File folder = new File(n);

        final String[] extension = {".txt"};
        String[] files = folder.list(new FilenameFilter() {

            @Override public boolean accept(File folder, String name) {
                for(String ext : extension)
                    if(name.toLowerCase().endsWith(ext)) return true;

                return false;
            }

        });

        for(String fileName : files)
            try {


                FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);
                LineNumberReader lineNumberReader = new LineNumberReader(fileReader);

                int lineNumber = 0;

                while (lineNumberReader.readLine() != null) {
                    lineNumber++;
                }

                System.out.println(lineNumber);

                lineNumberReader.close();

                String lineNumber1 = String.valueOf(lineNumber);
                File newFile = new File("d:\\myFile.txt");
                FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(newFile);
                fileWriter.write(lineNumber1 + " Строк в файле: " + n);
                fileWriter.close();

                System.out.println("File: " + fileName);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: В чем проявляется немощьность?

Comment: @RomanC не могу вытащить переменные каждого файла, чтобы провести над ними функцию подсчета количества строк

Comment: объявите переменную класа и засовывайте туда ваши файлы, неважно какая функция подсчета, ыв все равно ее не писали.

Comment: @RomanC функцию подсчета я написал. А вот как мне из переменной files вытащить каждый элемент находящий в ней и провести над ним операцию я никак не пойму..

Comment: у элемента должен быть тип, без понимания этого у вас ничего не получится

Comment: @RomanC ну у меня массив строк, а мне нужно из этого массива вытаскивать по 1 каждый элемент, он же является названием файла в директории, дальше просто применяю к каждому из элементов функцию подсчета. вот так я вижу этот код, но не особо понимаю как написать..

Comment: но из этого ничего не получится, потому-что у вас только названия файлов, а самих файлов нету.

Comment: @RomanC почему же, если я смогу вывести каждую переменную из массива, а она же и является названием файла, я могу просто перед ней дописать путь, который вводит пользователь, и получится абсолютный адрес, которому я даю переменную и вставляю в  FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(ВОТ СЮДА);  и всё получается

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.LineNumberReader;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Blabla {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Введите абсолютный путь: ");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String inputValue = scanner.next();
        File folder = new File(inputValue);

        final String[] extension = {".txt"};
        File[] files = folder.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
            @Override
            public boolean accept(File folder, String name) {
                for (String ext : extension) {
                    if (name.toLowerCase().endsWith(ext)) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (File fileName : files) {
            try {
                FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);
                LineNumberReader lineNumberReader = new LineNumberReader(fileReader);
                int lineNumber = 0;
                while (lineNumberReader.readLine() != null) {
                    lineNumber++;
                }
                lineNumberReader.close();
                sb.append(lineNumber).append(" Строк в файле: ").append(fileName).append("\r\n");
                System.out.println(lineNumber);
                System.out.println("File: " + fileName);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Logger.getLogger(Blabla.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
            }
        }

        File newFile = new File("d:\\myFile.txt");
        try {
            FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(newFile);
            fileWriter.write(sb.toString());
            fileWriter.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Blabla.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: если правильно понял вашу проблему, то решение выглядит так

Comment: @269255 именно так как я и хотел, спасибо. Но тут проблема в том, что файл постоянно переписывается, по этому записывает только последнее значение, а не всех файлов

Comment: какой файл постоянно переписывается? прошу поподробнее

Comment: @269255 myFile.txt, я так понял он просто заново создается для каждого файла, а так как имя myFile.txt одно и то же, он просто переписывается, ну и на последнем значении останавливается

Comment: ну, разумеется, если вы FileWriter крутите в цикле , вместе с коллекцией ваших файлов, каждый раз пишите новый файл... надо вынести его из цикла и все ок. код переписал

Comment: @269255 так то оно да, но как же хочется развидеть logging )) спасибо

Comment: а что тут вас тут смущает? писать FileWriter в цикле - это бредовая идея. представьте, что у вас тысячи файлов. что, несколько тысяч раз переписать текстовый файл, а перед этим еще ж надо каждый раз его прочитать? чтение-запись - одна из самых медленных операций. подумайте, прежде, чем загнать такое в цикл...

Answer (score 1):

На вид задача учебная, поэтому предложу словесный алгоритм:

1. Получаем адрес от пользователя
2. Проверяем директория ли это (File.isDirectory)
3. Если это папка, то берем все её папки и идем по ним. У каждого вложенного файла проверяем:

   3.1. Если file директория, рекурсивно возвращаемся к началу п.3

   3.2. Если file файл, проверяем расширение и если txt то заносим в лист
4. На выходе п3 получаем лист файлов с расширение txt
5. Идем по всем txt файлам и считаем строки
6. Выводим количество строк.

---

Если немного покопаетесь, то можете воспользоваться Files.walkFileTree(), который пункты 1-3 сделает за вас.

Comment: зачем вы расписали по пунктам то, что я написал в описании и в комментариях ниже?